# How to refresh CDIView to reflect changes made in another CDIView?

Tags: java, navigation, vaadin, cdi

I am using `cdi-helpers` addon and my `UI` extends `ViewMenuUI`. I have `CDIViews` like

**OGSContractView**

```
@UIScoped
@CDIView("Contract")
@ViewMenuItem(order = ViewMenuItem.DEFAULT, icon = FontAwesome.BANK)
public class OGSContractView extends CssLayout implements View{ 
    // There's some UI Fields and some Functions to refresh the UI Fields
    public void RefreshList(){...}
}
```

and

**SchoolView**

```
@UIScoped
@CDIView("School")
@ViewMenuItem(order = ViewMenuItem.DEFAULT, icon = FontAwesome.BANK)
public class SchoolView extends CssLayout implements View{
    //Some UI and functions inside
    //here, after some changes, I want to call a Refresh_Function 
    //from my OGSContractView class
    someData.saveInDatabase();
    ogsContractView.refreshList(); // here is my problem
}
```

In `SchoolView`, I am changing some data in the database and after that I want to call `OGSContractView.refreshList()` to update some ui fields there.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For updated question. You do not need to call `refresh()` from the another view.

You can override method `public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event)` on `OGSContractView`, like

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
   refresh():
}
```

Above method is called by internal navigator each time you enter to that view.

Comment: @RezaPayambari added update to answer in case you do not have direct reference to view (how to do it without injecting).

Comment: Yes! It was a stupid mistake to ask a false Question. But still, I need to use a Navigator or it doesn't need Navigator in this case, also in `ViewMenuUI`?

Comment: @RezaPayambari No need for a navigator anymore it is used by ViewMenuUI internally as i looked at the code. Just implement that method in my updated answer. I believe it is what you need. BTW: i deleted my comments from this answer that were not anymore valid. please do the same to keep site clean :)